# Treat subsubsections differently when referencing

Tags: renewcommand

My document numbers chapters and sections like this:

```
1. Chapter
  1.1 Section
    1.1.1 Subsection
      Subsubsection
```

For the first subsection `\subsection{First}\label{subsec:first}`, for example, `cleveref` would correctly reference:

```
As described in \cref{subsec:first}` lorem ipsum...
```

as

```
As described in Section 1.1.1 lorem ipsum...
```

However, since subsubsections do not have numbering, any

```
\cref{subsubsec:first-subsubsec}
```

just results in the same

```
Section 1.1.1
```

reference.

I would like to have the subsubsection named, so for

```
\subsubsection{Apples}\label{subsubsec:apples}
...
\subsubref{subsubsec:apples}
```

It would produce `1.1.1 Apples` instead of just `1.1.1` where the reference to the actual subsubsection would get lost.

So far, I implemented this via:

```
\newcommandx{\subsubref}[1]{\cref{#1} \nameref{#1}}
```

Is there any way to dynamically decide what is being referenced and treat subsubsections differently?

In simple pseudo-code:

```
if type of ref == subsubsection:
    \cref{#1} \nameref{#1}
else:
    \cref{#1}
```

Comment: Note that you are much more likely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and work with as is

Comment: From the duplicate: if you copy all the code and change the `\creflabelformat` line to `\creflabelformat{subsubsection}{#2#1 \nameref*{\@lastusedlabel}#3}` it gives the desired output.